# Create an enum or use .class to switch between the types in java?

Tags: java, enums

I have come across a lot of scenarios where you have to switch between the type of object you need to interact with. And there comes 2 possibilities of switching between them
1. Using .class as their identifier
2. Using an enum

For example if I have a website type and I need to switch between the types. I can create an enum

```
enum WebsiteType { Blog, Shop }
```

Then we can pass in this type to a function and switch between the type. Or if we have classes with the same name like

```
class Blog { } class Shop { }
```

In that case we can also do

```
void SwitchBetweenType(Class websiteType) {
    switch(websiteType) {
        case Blog.class:
            break;
        case Shop.class:
            break;
    }
}
```

What is the better approach?

Comment: I assume these classes are in a heirarchy like shape-> circle and shape->triangle?

Comment: Enum constants should be UPPERCASE, and `Class`, like any other generic type, should never be used as a raw type. Method names should be camelCase.

Comment: Assuming they are just going to be POJO, what should be the right choice?

Comment: A couple technical points: (1) You cannot `switch` on a `Class` (2) `Class` is a generic type, and you should avoid raw generic types whenever possible.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information.  A lot depends on what `SwitchBetweenType` is going to do.  If you have `Blog` and `Shop` classes that will do something interesting, and you already have an object that is one of those types, making them subclasses of the same base class and using polymorphism seems best, unless the classes aren't yours and you can't change them.  If the purpose of the method is to _create_ an object of the class, passing in a `Class` might be best.  If there won't be any objects either way, then don't define classes that will never get used--use an `enum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible approach would be to leverage [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) design pattern, e.g.

```
interface Website {
     void doSomething(Platform platform)
}

class Blog extends Website {

    public void doSomething(Platform platform) {
        platform.doBlogTask();
    }
}

class Shop extends Website {

    public void doSomething(Platform platform) {
        platform.doShopTask();
    }    
}

class Platform {

    public doShopTask() {
       // Put specific logic here
    }

    public doBlogTask() {
       // Put specific logic here
    }

    void switchBetweenType(Website website) {
        // Instead of switch-case using polymorphism.
        website.doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

This way you delegate to polymorphism to decide which logic to execute based on dynamic type. In case you need to do some logic specific to dynamic type, you can actually refactor code above a bit to use double dispatch.

```
interface Website {
     void doSomething(Platform platform)
}

class Blog extends Website {

    public void doSomething(Platform platform) {
        platform.doTask(this);
    }
}

class Shop extends Website {

    public void doSomething(Platform platform) {
        platform.doTask(this);
    }    
}

class Platform {

    public doTask(Shop shop) {
       // Now you can work with shop variable
       shop.payCart();
    }

    public doTask(Blog blog) {
       // Now you can work with blog variable
       blog.postEntry("New blog entry");
    }

    void switchBetweenType(Website website) {
        // Instead of switch-case using polymorphism.
        website.doSomething(this);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to avoid any kind of casting since resolution will be done based on dynamic typing, e.g. purely using polymorphic behavior of instances.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Blog* and *Shop* do not include any logic themselves, you could and maybe should indeed use *Enum* as its intended for cases like that.

But if they do include logic, then most likely you would make use of inheritance and polymorphism in object oriented programming.  *Website* would be the super class and *Blog* and *Shop* its sub classes. Then there's usually also no more need for switching, but of course depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Example:

```
public abstract class Website {
  public abstract void doMyAction();
}

public class Blog extends Website {
  @Override
  public void doMyAction() {
    System.out.println("I'm a blog");
  }
}

public class Shop extends Website {
  @Override
  public void doMyAction() {
    System.out.println("I'm a shop");
  }
}
```

Then you could create instances and call its method without knowing its actual type like this:

```
List<Website> sites = new ArrayList<>();
sites.add(new Blog());
sites.add(new Shop());

for (Website site : sites) {
  site.doMyAction();
}
```

In this case you could make *Website* an Interface as well.